# Use conditions with date time python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm working with DateTime in my df that looks like this:

| Time stamp | Datetime | time | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018/02/21,11:00 | 2018-02-21 11:00:00 | 11:00:00 |  |
| 2018/02/21,10:55 | 2018-02-2110:55. | 10:55:00 |  |
| 2018/02/21,11:00 | 2018-02-21 11:00:00 | 11:00:00 |  |

the value in the column "category" depends on specific conditions.

conditions:

0:00<time<6:00 = "b"

6:00<=time<20:00 = "i"

22:00<=time<24:00 = "i"

20:00<=time<22:00 = "p"

I tried to create a function :

```
def categories (row):
    if row["Time"]> 0 and row["Time"] <6:
        return "B"

df.apply (lambda row: categories(row), axis=1)
```

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'int'
```

how can I create the conditions???

Comment: convert those `datetime.time` objects to type `int` or vice-versa.

Comment: Are you working with pandas? If so, using pandas datetime is much simpler imho; for example as shown in the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69335114/10197418).

Answer (score 0):

As the error says youre comparing something of datetime to int, it doesnt how to calculate if 11:00:00 is greater than the value "6", you can compare against a datetime.time instead of an int

if row["Time"] > datetime.time(0,0,0) and row["Time"] < datetime.time(6,0,0)

the time constructor looks like
*time(hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0)*

Comment: TypeError: descriptor 'time' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'

Comment: it depends how you are importing datime, try time() on its own, datetime.time(), or datetime.datetime.time()